# FireZilla: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: ftp, sftp

I am able to connect by ssh in the terminal but SFTP does not work, I am using FireZilla.

```
Status:         Connecting to 123.45.67.89...
Status:         Using username "myuser". 
Error:          FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:          Could not connect to server
Status:         Waiting to retry...
```

I set a new SFT site from Site Manager and I am using Mac.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this issue like this:

[image: Official FireZilla docs]

https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto#On_a_Mac